# Move file after downloading from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, file, asp.net-core, amazon-s3

Unable to Download a file from AWS S3 to the Downloads folder. However file is getting downloaded from AWS S3 server to the intermediate local server (E:\New**\E***\wwwroot\DownloadFiles). Now the issue is getting this file from (\DownloadFiles) this folder to the Downloads folder. Getting a error pop-up on attempting so.

```
return File(memory, tmpConType, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
```

Error Popup

[Error-Popup-fromBrowser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBFVB.png)

Here is my full code for Download:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadFile(string fileName, string originalFilename, int clientId, int taskId)
    {
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("UserId", userId))
        {
            try
            {
                if (fileName != null && fileName != "")
                {
                    var fName = fileName.Split("_")[0];
                    var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(accesskey, secretkey, bucketRegion);
                    var s3companyFolder = "Company-" + companyId + "/" + "Client-" + clientId + "/" + "Job-" + taskId;

                    GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest
                    {
                        BucketName = bucketName + "/" + s3companyFolder,
                        Key = fName
                    };

                    using (GetObjectResponse response = await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request))
                    {
                        using Stream responseStream = response.ResponseStream;
                        string tmpName = response.Metadata["x-amz-meta-filename"];
                        var tmpConType = response.Headers["Content-Type"];

                        
                        string filePath = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "DownloadFiles");
                        filePath = Path.Combine(filePath, tmpName);
                        using FileStream outFile = System.IO.File.Create(filePath);
                        responseStream.CopyTo(outFile);
                        outFile.Dispose();
                        responseStream.Dispose();

                        var memory = new MemoryStream();
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
                        {
                            await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
                        }

                        if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                            System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);

                        memory.Position = 0;
                        return File(memory, tmpConType, Path.GetFileName(filePath));
                    }
                }
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This line is specifically saying that you want to download it into the `wwwroot` path: `string filePath = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "DownloadFiles");` If you want to download the file somewhere else, just provide a different destination.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein But the same line code is working in different application.But not working in this application.